# mysql worbench. how to create database if I have model

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am novice in mysql server.

I use latest version of worbench.

using designer I created model:
[image]

But in databases I don't see my model:

[image]

I bad in mysql termins But I want to get so thing where I can insert data to Student and Group tables.

Answer (score 0):

Modeling is more an abstract work to develop your schema structure systematically. It helps you to define needed objects, their relationships, users etc. that are needed. A model however has no data or any real representation of the objects it contains.

In order to use the objects you have to bring them on a real server. There are different ways to accomplish that, for instance you can forward engineer your model to a server (see Database menu). You have to select (or create) a connection to a server of your choice and let MySQL Workbench generate and apply a script to generate all the objects. Once this is done you can open those objects in the SQL IDE to fill them with data or work on them.

MySQL Workbench also has a synchronization feature that you can use after forward engineering. It's a two-way sync that allows to apply changes in your model to the schema objects on your server and also take over any changes made there into your model. All that can be fine tuned in the sync wizard.